# How to add a reference to a file in xcodeproj without going through xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I through the objective-c in the `writeToFile: atomically: encoding: error:` method to generate some .h and .m files, but after the file generation I have to xcode in add files to "projectName" this way into the file Project, there is no way in the document generation, to operate xcodeproj, xcodeproj the introduction of the document automatically added?
I compare tools through the beyond compare two xcodeproj documents found in the differences

[image]